# How should I deploy Traefik in my environment?

Tags: load-balancing, high-availability, traefik

I have a set of applications that we're currently transitioning into a more "cloud-native" architecture. We're beginning by moving them into containers (Docker on Windows), and as part of this, we're hoping to use a load-balancing proxy to handle traffic to the containers.

Having looked at several options, we're hoping to use Traefik as a load-balancing proxy in this iteration of our architecture. It may or may not be important to note that all traffic through Traefik in this setup will be internal; it will not be serving any external traffic. I am also working in a self-hosted situation; because of contractual concerns, cloud providers such as AWS and Azure are not currently available to me.

My question, now, is how Traefik might best be deployed. I can see at least two options:

First, Traefik could be deployed on separate "load-balancer" hosts. I could use round-robin DNS for these hosts, and pass traffic through them.

Second, Traefik could be deployed on each of my application hosts. In this setup, Traefik would be more of a "side-car", and applications on each host would use the local Traefik instance as a proxy to the other hosts' services.

An issue I see is that in neither of these setups is true high availability achieved. In either case, a Traefik instance crashing would result in unavailability for at least some services. In the first case, round-robin DNS and short TTL might mitigate this?

Is lack of high-availability avoidable? Is there an alternative way to architect this solution? Does Traefik itself offer guidance on how this solution should be structured?